# Retrofit: response 500, Internal Server Error

Tags: java, android, django, retrofit2

I am working on a project. The web team has implemented the API for signup and login. I will implement the Android part. So when I post a request to the server to sign up, using Postman, It is working. But When I try to signup in Android, It returns 500-Internal Server Error. I used Retrofit for sending request. Here is my code:

**SignUpActivity.java:**

```
public class SingUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    final EditText gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    final EditText location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);

    Button btn_signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

    btn_signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email_str = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String username_str = username.getText().toString().trim();
            String password_str = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email_str) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(username_str) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password_str))
            {
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "username: " + username_str + " email: "+ email_str + " password: " + password_str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendPost(username_str, email_str, password_str);
            }
        }
    });

}

public void sendPost(String email, String username, String password){
    Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getApiClient();

    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<JsonResponseSignUp> call = apiInterface.signUp(new SignUpBody(username,  email, password));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponseSignUp>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponseSignUp> call, Response<JsonResponseSignUp> response) {

            if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry for inconvince server is down" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("response", response.raw().body().toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponseSignUp> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR while posting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

**ApiClient.java**

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://my-aws-url.com";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@Headers( {"Content-Type: application/json" })
@POST("/api/users/signup")
Call<JsonResponseSignUp> signUp(@Body SignUpBody signup);
Call<User> signIn();}
```

**JsonResponseSignUp.java**

```
public class JsonResponseSignUp {
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private User user;

@SerializedName("profile")
@Expose
private Profile profile;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public Profile getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

public JsonResponseSignUp(Profile profile,User user ) {
    this.user = user;
    this.profile = profile;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}}
```

**Profile.java**

```
public class Profile {
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("username")
private String username;

@SerializedName("location")
private String location;

@SerializedName("gender")
private String gender;

@SerializedName("photo_path")
private String photo_path;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public String getPhoto_path() {
    return photo_path;
}

public Profile(int id, String username, String location, String gender, String photo_path) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.location = location;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.photo_path = photo_path;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public void setPhoto_path(String photo_path) {
    this.photo_path = photo_path;
}}
```

**SignUpBody.java**

```
public class SignUpBody {
public String username;
public String email;
public String password;


public SignUpBody(String username, String email, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("username")
private String username;

@SerializedName("email")
private String email;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public User(String username, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}}
```

And Here is the server log (API is done using Django-Rest-Framework):

```
 raise AssertionError(msg) AssertionError: You must call `.is_valid()` before accessing `.errors`.
```

**Postman Json Request that worked properly**
POST:

```
{"username" : "userfdsar","email":"userrr@gmail.com","password":"passs1234"}
```

RESPONSE:

`{"profile":{"id":15,"username":"user5","location":"","gender":"","photo_path":""},"user":{"email":"userrr5@gmail.com","username":"user5"}}`

I spent many hours to solve this, If you find what I am doing wrong, I will appreciate that, Thanks.

Comment: could u please also add the postman post request and response body that worked properly

Comment: @Vishal I have seen all the related questions on stackoverflow and  on many other sites. Believe me it is not duplicate. In that question he was supposed to use list. I am not using list in API.

Comment: @Niraj Sanghani Sure, I am adding.

Comment: you have still problems ??

Comment: Not enough information. Please screenshot the `Postman` request or the raw `HTTP` request from it. There is a different in your request between `Postman` and `Retrofit` that cause the server to return 500. You should not only check the server error log but also the raw request coming from both `Postman` and `Retrofit`.

Comment: There is a mistake in the server that hiding the original error (`before accessing .errors`)

Answer (score 2):

Your server might handling data in encoded form, Try this code

```
@POST("/api/users/signup")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<JsonResponseSignUp> signUp( @Field("username") String username, @Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

Comment: My api's content type is json , so I can not use FormUrlEncoded and Field.